# Laravel on Kubernetes - CronJob swift 550 5.7.1 Relaying denied

Tags: laravel, kubernetes, cron

I've deployed a Laravel app on Kubernetes.
Inside the app, mails are sent without any problems.

I wrote a Laravel command to send notifications, and deployed a Kubernetes CronJob to schedule the command.
The command is fired as wished, but when it tries to send the notifications i got this error :

```
swift 550 5.7.1 Relaying denied
```

I tried with 2 differents MAIL_HOST (ssl0.ovh.net and smtp.gmail.com). Both use SMTP.

Any help appreciated !

Thanks in advance,
Julien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i had to add my env variables in the cron config file